# Method scope - not sure if method should an be instance or class method

Tags: ruby, scope

I'm doing an exercise that comes with pre-written tests. At first, the tests seem to be calling a method called `to` on an instance of the class `SumOfMultiples` like so:

```
  def test_sum_to_1000
    assert_equal 233_168, SumOfMultiples.to(1000)
  end
```

As such, I've written my class as follows:

```
class SumOfMultiples
  @@multiples = [3, 5]

  def initialize *multiples
    @@multiples = multiples unless multiples.empty?
  end

  def self.to num
    sum  = 0

    (0..num-1).each { |e| sum += e if (@@multiples.any? { |m| e % m == 0 }) }
    sum
  end
end
```

Now I've come across tests that call `to` directly on `SumOfMultiples`:

```
  def test_configurable_7_13_17_to_20
    assert_equal 51, SumOfMultiples.new(7, 13, 17).to(20)
  end
```

The above test fails because I have `to` defined as an instance method which is what was needed to get the previous tests to pass. Am I getting something fundamentally wrong with regards the scope of the `to` method?

**Notes**

1. I'm not a student, this is something I'm doing on my own.
2. For the moment I have `@@multiples` defined as a global variable because I needed to access it in `initialize` AND `to` - if I've gotten the scope of wrong this will likely change.
3. For those of you who want to know - the aim of this exercise is to write a program that, given a number, can find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 up to but not including that number. We also have to allow the program to be configured to find the sum of multiples of
   numbers other than 3 and 5.

**After following Alex Tetzlaff's suggestions**

I've changed the scope of `@multiples` so that it's an instance variable. At first I skipped over all the tests except for `test_configurable_7_13_17_to_20` and I changed the scope of `to` so that it was an instance method - everything passed

Then I tried running `test_sum_to_1000` again - it failed because it couldn't see `@multiples`

Next I changed the scope of `to` back to a class method so it's now `self.to` and I set `@multiples` by calling `self.class.new` - so my full `SumOfMultiples` class now looks like:

```
class SumOfMultiples
  @multiples = [3, 5]

  def initialize *multiples
    @multiples = multiples unless multiples.empty?
  end

  def self.to num
    self.class.new
    sum  = 0

    (0..num-1).each { |e| sum += e if (@multiples.any? { |m| e % m == 0 }) }
    sum
  end
end
```

`test_configurable_7_13_17_to_20` now fails with `undefined method 'to' for #<SumOfMultiples:0x000000010b0198 @multiples=[7, 13, 17]>`

TL;DR I am still very, very confused about the scope of the `to` method and what exactly the tests are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing @@multiples as global, or more precise 'class variable' is a major design flaw.

`initialize` will be called multiple times, and every time alter the behaviour of the `to`-method for *all* instances.

```
 def test_configurable_7_13_17_to_20
    sm1= SumOfMultiples.new(7, 13, 17)
    sm2=SumOfMultiples.new(1,2,4)
    assert_equal 51, sm1.to(20) # will probably fail
 end
```

So to not give it all away, since it's an exercise: Try to make it an instance variable and solve the second case first. Then write the static method using an instance created on the fly.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll try this and get back to you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not much further. I've set multiples to be an instance variable but I'm still confused about the scope of `to` - I've updated my question with what I've tried so far.

Comment: You nearly got it ;-) make your `to`method an instance method - this way you can access your instance variable `@multiples`! Then create an extra `self.to` method - there you can call `self.new.to(num)` - so the trick is two have two `to`methods ;-)

Comment: This is now giving the error `undefined method 'any' for nil:NilClass` on `test sum to 1000` :(  - Any hints as to why `@multiples` is not being seen?

Comment: Okay solved it - `initialize` now reads `multiples.empty? ? @multiples = [3, 5] : @multiples = multiples` - Thanks for all your help!